# Changing Chart Size in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I would like to be able to change the size of a chart in matplotlib. I have so far only been able to change the size of the window, but not the chart. I haven't been able to locate anything about this in documentation.

My Code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 5,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to modify your rcParams if you don't want to, you can pass the `figsize` as a keyword when you make the figure.  For changing the size of the Axes (I believe that's what you mean by 'chart'), the `position` keyword is what you're looking for if you use `add_subplot`, or just the input parameter if you use `add_axes`.  You specify it as *[left, bottom, width, height]*.  The relevant documentation is [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, position=[0.01, 0.01, 0.98, 0.98])
```